# How can I make Quartz.NET AdoJobStore work with Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, quartz.net

- .NET 4.51
- Entity Framework 6.x

I have a separate project / assembly that wraps the core Quartz.NET functionality. I want to programatically configure Quartz.NET to persist information to SQL Server. As this is a separate assembly the App.config is very minimal and I want to pass in a connection string. Here is the **complete** App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
    </configuration>
```

and here is the code I am using to configure Quartz.NET:

```
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "My Scheduler";
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "MySchedulerId";
properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true";
properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
properties["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = aConnectionString;
properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "System.Data.SqlClient";
properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_";
```

The value for aConnectionString is:

**TESTING**

```
"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

**PRODUCTION**

```
server=sql.server.com;User Id=xxxx;password=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;database=xxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient
```

However when I attempt to call GetScheduler() I receive the following error message:

```
Could not Initialize DataSource: default
```

and the inner exception has:

```
{"There is no metadata information for provider 'System.Data.SqlClient'\r\nParameter name: providerName"}
```

So what am I missing here? What do I have to change to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quartz does not support plugging in Entity Framework infrastructure, it works without external frameworks. Quartz's provider is different from ADO.NET's provider infrastructure. You can see an programmatic configuration example for AdoJobStore in [Example 13](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz.Examples/example13/ClusterExample.cs). So the correct value would be **SqlServer-20**.

You can also configure the connection string by providing parameter **connectionStringName** and Quartz will look for that named connection string from connectionStrings section.

Comment: Agreed. You are dependent on using the built-in providers...which currently are only ADO.NET based (for Sql Server).  They also use alot of generic SQL statements to minimize what is needed between different RDBMS's.  But feel free to write an EF based one..(if you have time)...and post the code....   :O

Comment: I did see the SqlServer-20 one. What NuGet packages are needed to make that work in .NET 4.51? I seem to recall that that was dependent on .NET 2 libraries. So I guess there is some form of "translation" needed in web.config to say use these "new" assemblies? What are the necessary statements?

Comment: Nothing special should be needed, GAC has automatic mappings for you so the provider resolves with bare .NET 4.5.x cleanly.

Comment: @MarkoLahma Changing the provider name and passing the actual connection string and it all worked like a charm. Thanks for that.

Comment: Does Quartz.net automatically create the required tables like the .NET providers do or do I just need to pass in the connection string? If it does create tables, are these documented anywhere?

Comment: Quartz does not automatically create tables at the moment. One needs to manually run the scripts to create the tables. See scripts here: https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/tree/master/database/tables